# Neo4J - FOREACH CASE WHEN PATH EXISTS, DELETE RELATIONSHIP

Tags: foreach, neo4j, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to match a parent-child relationship. I have a case where a child node may link to a different 'grandparent'. In this case, I want to delete the relationship between the child and the grandparent so that I mitigate the potential issue that the grandparent is recognised also as a child node and is then deleted.

```
MATCH (c: itemContainer {uuid: "$ID"})<-[:HAS_VERSION]-(cv: itemContainerVersion {version: 1})
WITH c, cv
MATCH (parent)-[*0..]-(child)
WHERE (parent)--(cv)-[:HAS_VERSION]->(c)
WITH DISTINCT parent, child, cv, c
MATCH (child)-[cvr]-(n)--(cv2: itemContainerVersion)
WITH child, cv, c, cvr
    FOREACH(i IN CASE WHERE exists(cvr) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | DELETE cvr)
    FOREACH(i IN CASE WHERE NOT exists(cvr) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | DETACH DELETE child)
DETACH DELETE parent, cv, c
RETURN parent, child, cv, c
```

I get an issue in the first `FOREACH` statement:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'x': expected 'n/N' (line 10, column 27 (offset: 351))
"   FOREACH(i IN CASE WHERE exists(cvr) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | DELETE cvr)"
                       ^
```

I don't understand why this is broken. It seems to be an issue with the `exists()` - maybe a type error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHEN` instead of `WHERE`.

```
MATCH (c: itemContainer {uuid: "$ID"})<-[:HAS_VERSION]-(cv: itemContainerVersion {version: 1})
WITH c, cv
MATCH (parent)-[*0..]-(child)
WHERE (parent)--(cv)-[:HAS_VERSION]->(c)
WITH DISTINCT parent, child, cv, c
MATCH (child)-[cvr]-(n)--(cv2: itemContainerVersion)
WITH child, cv, c, cvr
    FOREACH(i IN CASE WHEN exists(cvr) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | DELETE cvr)
    FOREACH(i IN CASE WHEN NOT exists(cvr) THEN [1] ELSE [] END | DETACH DELETE child)
DETACH DELETE parent, cv, c
RETURN parent, child, cv, c
```